# Android Calendar Intent event end always one hour after start, API level 8+

Tags: java, android, android-intent, calendar

I understand that this same title was used before, but the specific question (and answer) was used with the ContentValues class, which is Api level 14+; my program uses minimum of Api level 8.  I use the Intent with putextra to add my values to the calendar:

```
            Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            beginTime.set(year, month, day, fromHour, fromMin, 0);
            Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            endTime.set(year, month, day, toHour, toMin, 0);

            long startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
            long endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra("beginTime", startMillis);
            intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
            intent.putExtra("endTime", endMillis);
            intent.putExtra("title", strSelected);
            intent.putExtra("description", strSelected+" for "+minDiff+
                    " minutes burning "+calorieBurned+" calories");
            intent.putExtra("eventLocation", "Gym");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Where year, month, day, fromHour, fromMin, etc are variables defined in above code.  The calendar works for all of these values except the end time, where is it an hour after the start time no matter what the start time is.  When I compared startMillis to endMillis, both were correct (and therefore endMillis was more than 1 hour from startMillis), so the correct end date is being passed to the calendar but the calendar does not seem to adjust correctly.

If I remove the intent.putExtra("endTime", endMillis); 
code completely, the start date remains correct, but the end date reverts to the default (1970's).  Therefore the calendar is recognizing the line of code, but simply not using the correct endMillis value, or is stuck at displaying only the hour after the start date.

Even if I input an end time less than an hour after the start time, the calendar still displays an hour after the start date.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: So is this issue occurring on a device running API 8? (2.2) Or is it occurring on a device running a later version of Android.

Comment: What happens if you change this `intent.putExtra("allDay", false);` to this `intent.putExtra("allDay", true);`?

Comment: NanaGeek - My device is API 10, but my minSdkVersion is 8.

Comment: Artoo Detoo - if I change "allDay" to true, then the From and To are set to the whole day, and the "All day" radio option is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is simply a bug in older Android phones; I got a new Android phone and it works perfectly without changing the code.

I don't think there will be a solution to the question besides updating the Android OS, since this is an unavoidable bug.